# Windows: How to launch different browsers based on url?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser

I use a few browser instances, all `Chrome` based (either different profiles or full-blown separate instances via various *hacks*).

I'd like the ability to launch different browser instances based on the URL or some other modifier (perhaps shortcut or other), for example:

- all with `amazon` or `ebay` = shopping browser
- all with `facebook` or `twitter` = social browser
- etc... you get the idea :)

Can that be done ?  On Mac I used to have an app which achieved just this, called `Choosy`. It would display a popup of browser choices when desired (regex rule based), but I have not found a similar Windows alternative. A system-wide one would be nice, anybody knows if it's possible ?

*Note: I've somewhat cross-posted this to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49246863/1408907), but there it's more aimed at developers on Intellij, so perhaps I'll get some other angles on this question...*

Comment: it could be done with greasemonkey scripts,

Comment: Not sure about windows, but a plain shell script `case` sounds very similar

Comment: if your browsers can be atarted correctly via command line, you can create a hashtable with information and start browsers depending on url

Answer (score 1):

I [found and tried a few alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/browser-chooser-2/) to achieve this.

On Mac I liked [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/)  which was great.

On Windows, I like [Browser Chooser](https://browserchooser2.com/), free & open-source. It catches system-wide links, outside of browsers (in explorer & other apps). Alas, currently no way to trigger this from inside the browser (*Choosy* does, via a companion extension).

Then it shows a popup browser selection list, it's also possible to define rules-based (regex, protocol) automatic routing of URLs to various browsers with command-line switches (for profile selection, etc). I don't use that part, I stick to choosing manually.

Fits *most* of my needs. I'm **(*still!*)** surprised not many more options exist. **(*wishful*)** Come on tech giants, don't you realize we'd be better off using MANY browsers instead of all fighting trying to be the ONLY ONE ??  Better browser selection *built-in* would improve our tech lives! **Mutualism**, not **exclusivity**, is best for all!